# MySQL replication -- issue with mysql.proc during replication from 5.0 to 5.5 host

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5, stored-procedures, mysql-5.0

We are replicating from a mysql 5.0.45 host to a 5.5.26 host over WAN. Every once in a while one of our databases does not accept a query and halts the replication.

"'Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 20, found 16. The table is probably corrupted' on query."

I found some useful information from this posting, but not specifically about replication. It seems like if you are upgrading, then you need to do the mysql_upgrade (with --force if needed) on that table. My guess is that the replication from 5.0 to 5.5 is like an upgrade...all of the time. So how would I do a mysql_upgrade here? If I do the upgrade followed by a slave start, will it be flushed out immediately as the data is still coming from a master without the upgrade?

[Resolving issue with mysql.proc after upgrading MySQL from 5.0.* to 5.1.*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/956/resolving-issue-with-mysql-proc-after-upgrading-mysql-from-5-0-to-5-1)

```
    mysql> show slave status\G
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
                  Master_Host: 192.168.15.61
                  Master_User: replica
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000016
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 1054186012
               Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.000431
                Relay_Log_Pos: 39375086
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000016
             Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 1547
                   Last_Error: Error 'Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 20, found 16. The table is probably corrupted' on query. Default database: 'ResumeDB'. Query: 'INSERT INTO `search` (zip_code,lat,lon,dist)
SELECT zipcode,latitude,longitude,GetDistance( NAME_CONST('lat1',32.84), NAME_CONST('long1',-83.68),B.latitude,B.longitude) as dist
FROM zipcodes AS B
WHERE
B.latitude BETWEEN  NAME_CONST('lat1',32.84)-( NAME_CONST('range',25)* NAME_CONST('rangeFactor',0.014457)) AND  NAME_CONST('lat1',32.84)+( NAME_CONST('range',25)* NAME_CONST('rangeFactor',0.014457))
AND B.longitude BETWEEN  NAME_CONST('long1',-83.68)-( NAME_CONST('range',25)* NAME_CONST('rangeFactor',0.014457)) AND  NAME_CONST('long1',-83.68)+( NAME_CONST('range',25)* NAME_CONST('rangeFactor',0.014457))
AND GetDistance( NAME_CONST('lat1',32.84), NAME_CONST('long1',-83.68),B.latitude,B.longitude) <=  NAME_CONST('range',25) ORDER BY dist'
                 Skip_Counter: 1
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 1053930692
              Relay_Log_Space: 39635387
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 1547
               Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 20, found 16. The table is probably corrupted' on query. Default database: 'ResumeDB'. Query: 'INSERT INTO `search` (zip_code,lat,lon,dist)
SELECT zipcode,latitude,longitude,GetDistance( NAME_CONST('lat1',32.84), NAME_CONST('long1',-83.68),B.latitude,B.longitude) as dist
FROM zipcodes AS B
WHERE
B.latitude BETWEEN  NAME_CONST('lat1',32.84)-( NAME_CONST('range',25)* NAME_CONST('rangeFactor',0.014457)) AND  NAME_CONST('lat1',32.84)+( NAME_CONST('range',25)* NAME_CONST('rangeFactor',0.014457))
AND B.longitude BETWEEN  NAME_CONST('long1',-83.68)-( NAME_CONST('range',25)* NAME_CONST('rangeFactor',0.014457)) AND  NAME_CONST('long1',-83.68)+( NAME_CONST('range',25)* NAME_CONST('rangeFactor',0.014457))
AND GetDistance( NAME_CONST('lat1',32.84), NAME_CONST('long1',-83.68),B.latitude,B.longitude) <=  NAME_CONST('range',25) ORDER BY dist'
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 40
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is fixed with a

```
mysql > slave stop; SET GLOBAL sql_slave_skip_counter = 1; slave start;
```

and replication picks up again. Obviously not a full replica of data when doing this more than a few times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the discrepancy is obvious.

When you run

```
SELECT A.*,B.* FROM (SELECT VERSION() MySQLVersion) A,
(SELECT COUNT(1) MySQLProcColumns FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema='mysql' AND table_name='proc') B;
```

you get

```
mysql> SELECT A.*,B.* FROM (SELECT VERSION() MySQLVersion) A,
    -> (SELECT COUNT(1) MySQLProcColumns FROM information_schema.columns
    -> WHERE table_schema='mysql' AND table_name='proc') B;
+-----------------------+------------------+
| MySQLVersion          | MySQLProcColumns |
+-----------------------+------------------+
| 5.0.51a-community-log |               16 |
+-----------------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.54 sec)

mysql>
```

and

```
mysql> SELECT A.*,B.* FROM (SELECT VERSION() MySQLVersion) A,
    -> (SELECT COUNT(1) MySQLProcColumns FROM information_schema.columns
    -> WHERE table_schema='mysql' AND table_name='proc') B;
+--------------+------------------+
| MySQLVersion | MySQLProcColumns |
+--------------+------------------+
| 5.5.8-log    |               20 |
+--------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

Here is a quick-and-dirty way to fix `mysql.proc`. Please pay attention:

STEP 01 : On the Slave DB Server, run `STOP SLAVE;`

STEP 02 : Install MySQL 5.5.26 on a Staging DB Server

STEP 03 : Copy the following files from that Staging DB Server to the Slave DB Server

- `/var/lib/mysql/mysql/proc.frm`
- `/var/lib/mysql/mysql/proc.MYD`
- `/var/lib/mysql/mysql/proc.MYI`

STEP 04 : On the Slave DB Server, run `FLUSH TABLES;`

STEP 05 : Dump the Stored Procedures on the Master DB Server

```
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="--routines --no-data --no-create-info --all-databases"
mysqldump -uroot -p ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} > StoredProc.sql
```

STEP 06 : Move `StoredProc.sql` from Master DB Server to /root on the Slave DB Server

STEP 07 : On the Slave DB Server, load the Stored Procedures

```
mysql -uroot -p -A < /root/StoredProc.sql
```

STEP 08 : On the Slave DB Server, run `START SLAVE;`

You should never encounter this issue any more.

Give it a Try !!!

## UPDATE 2013-04-22 12:45 EDT

Please run this query

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema='mysql' AND table_name='user';
```

For MySQL 5.0, you should get 37. For MySQL 5.5, you should get 42.

If you get 37 on the MySQL 5.5. server, go ahead with running [mysql_upgrade](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-upgrade.html).

If you get 42, run my original answer to fix `mysql.proc`.

Comment: I get `+--------------+------------------+
| MySQLVersion | MySQLProcColumns |
+--------------+------------------+
| 5.0.45-log   |               16 | 
+--------------+------------------+`
and `+--------------+------------------+
| MySQLVersion | MySQLProcColumns |
+--------------+------------------+
| 5.5.28       |               16 |
+--------------+------------------+`

Comment: Just I figured. You have a MySQL 5.0 version of `mysql.proc` in the MySQL 5.5 database.

Comment: yep. 37 on both servers. I will look further into the mysql_upgrade.

Comment: +1 running mysql_upgrade against the slave should do it... assuming mysql_upgrade for 5.5 understands how to migrate all the way from 5.0; however, replication from 5.0 to 5.5 isn't officially a valid configuration (though it most likely should be fine) since: "MySQL supports replication from one major version to the next higher major version"  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-compatibility.html ... if the master can't be upgraded, the safest/most officially proper configuration for the slave would be the latest version of 5.1, not 5.5.

Comment: looks like this did the trick for now. I haven't seen any skips in about 24 hours. I also added "slave-skip-errors = 1547" in the my.cnf because I was skipping it anyways. After a day or so I'll have to re-import the master and do the upgrade again to ensure I have an actual replica.